# Owin Authentication creates a redirect loop

Tags: asp.net, redirect, webforms, asp.net-identity, owin

I have an ASP.NET 4.6 WebForms application which exploits the Identity 2.1 package for the registration and authentication system. It uses **Owin authentication**, not Forms or Windows.

My attempt is to allow no anonymous user to see any page of the website and to redirect them to the Login page. This is why I have added the following in my Web.config (according to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/751897/ASP-NET-Identity-with-webforms)) :

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="None" />
</system.web>

<location path="~/Account/Login.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Since then, I always get a Redirect Loop when running the app in the browser. I have found different solutions for MVC, but none for WebForms.

What may be the cause and how to remove it?

This is my Configuration method in the Startup.Auth.cs file:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login.aspx"),
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I had a similar situation recently. My login screen had a logout method in the page load method. The logout call had a redirect to the logout page. This led to a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Set authentication mode to "forms"
And set the authentication on the server to Formsauthentication & Anonymous.

Wait I look for another solution's :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<authentication mode="Forms" />
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>







<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

And remove the "`<deny users="?"/>`" Line

Comment: No, sorry, it is impossible. Look at this mention: "My attempt is to allow no anonymous user to see any page of the website and to redirect them to the Login page". And why should I choose Forms over Owin?

Comment: But it is possible. you need in each function are not permitted to call anonymously to refer to the login. then you can turn on anonymous

Answer (score 0):

change location path from

```
<location path="~/Account/Login.aspx">
```

to

```
<location path="Account/Login.aspx">
```

and remove friendly urls

Answer (score 0):

Add this XML to your Accounts/Web.Config

```
<system.web>
     <authorization>
         <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

That solved the problem for me.

Note that is the Web.Config inside your Accounts folder

Answer (score 0):

I added both configuration to my web.config

```
<authentication mode="None"/>

<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>


<location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
</modules>
```

You'll need to change the Login.aspx to your own page, like Account/Login.aspx